# Ошибка при парсинге Battle.net

Tags: requests, cookie, https

Я пытаюсь спарсить данные аккаунта battle.net, скопировал куки и передал их в запросе. На выходе получаю такое чудо:

<!doctype html>var AccountSettingsProperties = {cookieConsentEnabled: true};var BlzCookieConsent = {host: 'battle.net', whitelistedCookies: []};(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl+ '&gtm_auth=OuscuuIgPq2snG1opFHgeA&gtm_preview=env-2&gtm_cookies_win=x';f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KS2VMMQ');
<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KS2VMMQ&amp;gtm_auth=OuscuuIgPq2snG1opFHgeA&amp;gtm_preview=env-2&amp;gtm_cookies_win=x" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden">
"use strict";!function(n){var o="/api/error-report";function t(e,r,n){void 0!==r[n]&&(e[n]=r[n])}function a(){var e,r;return{system:function(){var e={};e.clientTimeMillis=Date.now();var r=n.navigator;return t(e,r,"oscpu"),t(e,r,"hardwareConcurrency"),t(e,r,"deviceMemory"),e}(),network:(e={},void 0!==(r=n.navigator.connection)&&(t(e,r,"downlink"),t(e,r,"downlinkMax"),t(e,r,"effectiveType"),t(e,r,"rtt"),t(e,r,"type")),e),browser:function(){var e={};t(e,n&&n.location,"href"),t(e,n,"devicePixelRatio"),t(e,n,"innerHeight"),t(e,n,"innerWidth");var r=n.navigator;return t(e,r,"platform"),t(e,r,"userAgent"),t(e,r,"language"),t(e,r,"cookieEnabled"),e}()}}function e(e,r,n,o,t){var i=function(e,r,n,o,t){return{message:e,source:r,lineno:n,colno:o}}.apply(void 0,arguments);c({environment:a(),error:i}),console.error(t)}function c(e){console.info("An error occurred. Submitting report.");var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.open("POST",o),r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json"),r.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");var n=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]+)"));n&&n.length&&r.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN",n[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipfWY.png)),r.addEventListener("error",function(e){console.error("An error occurred while sending an error-report. Error: "+e)}),r.send(JSON.stringify(e))}void 0!==n?(n.onerror=e,n.errorReporter={global:e,vue:function(e,r,n){var o=function(e,r,n){return{stack:e.stack}}.apply(void 0,arguments);c({environment:a(),vueError:o}),console.error(e)}},console.debug("Listening for unhandled errors...")):console.error('Unable to bind onError listener as "window" was undefined.')}(window);

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно. Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

cookis = {"BA-tassadar-login.key": "123",
          "SESSIONID": "123",
          "login.cookies": "1",
          "login.key": "123",
          "loginChecked": "1",
          "opt": "1",
          "XSRF-TOKEN": "123-123-123-123-123"
          }


hes = {
        "Host": "account.battle.net",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "If-Modified-Since": "Thu, 28 Oct 2021 18:28:52 GMT",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "TE": "trailers",
    }

response = requests.get("https://account.battle.net/", headers=hes, cookies=cookis)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Многие сайты сейчас уже работают на JavaScript, а не отдают чистый HTML с данными. JS загружается в браузер, браузер этот код выполняет и получает остальные данные. Ваш код очевидно не умеет работать с JS, чтобы продвинуться дальше и вытащить всё остальное. А так выглядят начальные данные, ошибок тут нет. Обычно для таких вещей подключают еще Selenium.

Comment: @AlexKrass спасибо! попробую